# How to customize visualization blank mode

Tags: formatting, whitespace

I use blank-mode

I don't want the newlines to be displayed how can I turn it off.

Also long lines are shown in dark background how can I turn that off.

In fact I only want to display trailing whitespace, that gives me error on eslint.

Comment: I've red the documentation several times @Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the built-in replacement called `whitespace-mode`, instead of using an out-dated library from EmacsWiki that says:  "*It runs on Emacs 21, 22 and 23.  **Note**: This package was replaced by WhiteSpace*" ?  That being said, you can remove `newline` from the list of `blank-chars` like this:

```
(setq blank-chars
  '(tabs spaces trailing lines space-before-tab indentation empty space-after-tab))
```

Comment: Ok, I am using `whitespace-mode` now how do I do it in `whitespace-mode`?

Comment: Remove both `newline` and `newline-mark` from the variable list named `whitespace-style` -- e.g., `(setq whitespace-style '(face tabs spaces trailing lines space-before-tab indentation empty space-after-tab space-mark tab-mark))`